# What's wrong with my code, it won't recognize position?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-activity, android-edittext

I am making a simple planner app, with one xml and one activity. Here is MainActivity, where basically I take editText input, turn it into a listView item with button onClick, and save it. The only probmlem is my alert dialog for when you want to delete an item has an error - it won't recognize the word "position". I feel like it's just some dumb typo..? Thank you.

```
package com.kass.planner2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button btn;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        LoadPreferences();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String task = et.getText().toString();


                adapter.add(task);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
            }
        });

    // set ListView item listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view; final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Sure you want to delete?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });}

    protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();


    }

    protected void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", " ");

        adapter.add(dataSet);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    }`
```

Comment: Please consider choosing a better title to make it more explanatory of the problem

Comment: please explain more .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getListView().getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `position` variable needs to be `final` if you want to access it there.

Do it as follows:

```
final int p = position; // just before setPositiveButton
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(p));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly what you said but for some reason in the final int p = position, the "position" part is still an error. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: where did you put that line? it must be outside `setPositiveButtion`. Alternatively put it as a first line in `onItemClick` befoe you start building the AlertDialog

Comment: This is what that section of my code looks like: `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view; final int position, long id) {` That's the first line.

Comment: `alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position) {
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            });`

Comment: The first line has the final int position in it, I just think it might be a typo like a parenthesis supposed to be there or something? I have no idea. There is also an error on the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` part.

Answer (score 0):

May be, this  needed.... adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  when remove..

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                }
            });
```